# EntityQuery how to get all delta and good for field_dates

Tags: 8, database, datetime

I've got these dates linked to a node.

[image: Database node__field_dates]

I just want to make a request to render all node when `time()` is between `field_date_value` AND `field_date_end_value` OR `time()` is < to `field_date_value`

(ps: time() = 06-26)

I coded this for that :

[image]

And my render is :

[image]

So I think this code find some good value in database but is returning only 1 case with the first date which is wrong instead of the good which is the second and the third.

My wish :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you could already help your self by making your conditions more simple:

> just want to make a request to render all node when time() is between field_date_value AND field_date_end_value OR time() is < to field_date_value

So actually your final condition (which is equivalent with what you wrote is)
time() < field_date_end_value

Also I advice you to use the request time (from Time service) instead of time: in most of the case is that's what should be used.

Comment: Even without condition, it still return only 1.
In the `$events` var, I get `$events['%revision_id%'] = ['%node_id%']` maybe the prob come to this, because under this approach I must get unique entry.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you on this one: \